# Please help a person new to python (3x)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python. It is my first programming language and I am having a hard time comprehending what people think is simple (it probably is). It's making me feel stupid to say the least. I could very much use some pointers with something I am stuck on. Essentially what I need to do is create a program which will create a text file containing the words of 10 green bottles.

```
def kevin():
    file = open('greenbottles.txt','a')
    file.write(a)
    file.close()

def skinner():
    kevin('rabbits\n')

skinner()
```

This is what I've done so far to create and write to a text file. (The file should appear in same directory as the Python file is located according to what I've seen and read. I've noticed sometimes it doesn't appear?) When I open the file it should have rabbits written in it and `\n` means to force create a new line.

What I need to do is write the verses of the song in the text file using lists and variables. Also most of the song should be created in a loop (I thought a while loop would be best). I would be thankful if someone can give me some pointers on how to add a verse in.

> "Ten green bottles
>   Hanging on the wall
>   Ten green bottles
>   Hanging on the wall
>   And if one green bottle
>   Should accidentally fall
>   There'll be nine green bottles
>   Hanging on the wall"

One of the verses.

What I am expecting is that this code should create a text file containing the words rabbit. The `kevin` and `skinner` is what I named the functions so I could understand it a little better; they can be called whatever you would like.

Comment: What's `kevin` and `skinner`? And why there are two `green`

Comment: Could you please exactly specify what output are you expecting and what is the input? And why are there two `green` functions?

Comment: @JessicaSmith: Please edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: You need the variable `a` in `def kevin(a):` so that the `file.write(a)` can write the string to the file. Also, please remove most of the angst from your question.  It is relevant to say you're new to Python and that it is your first language — both those are important bits of information.  The rest of the 'disclaimers' and angst are not really necessary.

Comment: I removed some of the angst.

Comment: You should strive to create functions which perform a well-defined task, and name them accordingly.  Your `kevin` should be something like `writefile` perhaps, and `skinner` ... Is that supposed to just write `rabbit` to the file?  Then it's not a very meaningful function.  But maybe define a function which creates the next verse, and then call that ten times, and pass the output to `writefile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that will demystify the basic algorithm of the problem. Instead of doing exactly as you ask, it will just print the lyrics in some random format of my choosing. To understand this code, you have to understand lists, `for` loops, iteration, and output. Now it's your job to understand the code and make it do what you want it to do which is output to a file. If you have any trouble understanding the code, just ask.

This doesn't exactly answer your prompt, but since your question was basically just "how" you would loop through and create verses to the song, I wanted to make a simple demonstration with lists, `for` loops, and strings.

```
numbers = [
'Zero',
'One',
'Two',
'Three',
'Four',
'Five',
'Six',
'Seven',
'Eight',
'Nine',
'Ten' ]

text_one = 'green bottles hanging on the wall'
text_two = 'And if one green bottle should accidentally fall\nThere\'ll be'

# Each iteration of this loop prints one verse of the song
for i in range(10, 0, -1):
    print(numbers[i], text_one)
    print(numbers[i], text_one)
    print(text_two, numbers[i-1], text_one)
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying, also thank you for Lugubrious about the advice with naming my functions more appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

So,

I can see you are new, and one main way I can tell is that none of your function names make any sense!! One major thing about programming that can help people here on stack overflow help you is to give your functions/objects good names. Kevin and green are not useful names.

On that topic, making two green() [no idea what it was supposed to do from the name... maybe open would be a better name? or wrote?] functions will not allow you to use them both. Name one green1 and another green2, if you must.

Now, as far as your program, I think the general idea for doing it would be the following:

- Have one function called bottleText(i), where i is an integer. The bottleText returns the verse as a string. You might also want to import a function where you can convert an integer to a number or write the helper function yourself.
- Make a loop that calls your green() function and write the text to the file. I'd actually change the function to green(str) and make str the text to write.

Does that make any sense? If you have any questions, feel free to comment.

Comment: With the loop can I for instance create one so it will loop 10 times but change the output (So the one verse starts with 10 bottles and then the next verse it is 9 bottles)?

Comment: Yes, that is the point of a loop. Just watch https://www.khanacademy.org/science/computer-science/v/for-loops-in-python

Comment: Shashank Gupta demonstrated a way to do the loop in her post

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Python is picky with how you space things. In this example, you actually need to indent the code block that defines function "green". For example:

```
def green():
    file = open('greenbottles.txt','a')
    file.write(a)
    file.close()
```

I'm not sure why the file wouldn't appear, unless you forget to close the file, or maybe you don't have sufficient write privileges on the directory that you're in. Now, the second part of your code redefines the function green. If you want to use your function green, then you don't need the "def". If you want to insert variables into text, then you can 'interpolate' them  like this:

```
def green():
    my_variable = 10
    my_bottle_color = "green"
    my_string = "HI! I have %s %s bottles!" % (my_variable, my_bottle_color)
    file = open('greenbottles.txt','a')
    file.write(my_string)
    file.close()
```

Comment: Yeah, I had it like what you have right now but when i posted the question the website didn't like it? If that makes sense

Comment: @JessicaSmith: For posting code on SO, prepare it with blanks and not tabs, usually tabstops set to 4, and paste the code into the edit box.  Then highlight the code and press the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it all 4 spaces — so it will appear as code.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by reading http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/ That site has examples of how to create a loop that will solve your question independent of which language you are trying to write use. (It is also a good resource for any one new to a particular language.) Specifically for [python](http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-python-808.html)  you can start with any of their [examples](http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-python-1024.html) but read a few of them to try to see the underlying nature of the types of solutions. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it does what you want with added fetures:

```
def main():
    import time
    while True:
        try:
            num1 = int(input("Pick a number between 10 and 30: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("That's not a number!")
            continue
        if num1 > 30 or num1 < 10:
            print("Not Valid!")
            continue
       break           
    while True:
        try:
            hue = str(input("Pick a colour; Red, Green, Blue: ")) 
        except ValueError:
            print("Letters not numbers!") 
            continue                        
        if  (hue == "Red") or (hue == "red") or (hue == "Green") or (hue == "green") or (hue == "Blue") or (hue == "blue"):

            break
    print("Generating File")
    time.sleep(3)
    numbers ='no', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Eleven', 'Twelve', 'Thirteen', 'Fourteen', 'Fifteen', 'Sixteen', 'Seventeen', 'Eighteen', 'Nineteen', 'Twenty', 'Twentyone', 'Twentytwo', 'Twentythree', 'Twentyfour', 'Twentyfive', 'Twentysix', 'Twentyseven', 'Twentyeight', 'Twentynine', 'Thirty' 
    text_one = hue +' bottle%s\nHanging on the wall'
    text_two = "And if one " + hue + " bottle\nShould accidentally fall\nThere'll be"
    text_three =' \n'

    with open(numbers[num1] + ' ' + hue + ' Bottles.txt', 'w') as a:
        for l in range(num1, 0, -1):                                              
            a.write(numbers[l]+ ' ')
            if l == 1:
                a.write(text_one % '' +'\n')
            else:
                a.write(text_one % 's' +'\n')

            a.write(numbers[l] + ' ')
            if l == 1:
                a.write(text_one %  '' + '\n') 
            else:
                a.write(text_one % 's' +  '\n')
            a.write(text_two + ' ')
            a.write(numbers[l-1] + ' ')
            if (l - 1) ==1 :
                a.write(text_one % ''+'\n')
            else:
                a.write(text_one % 's'+'\n')
            a.write('\n' + '\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```